# Running GUI of JTS?

Tags: java, ubuntu, windows, jts-topology-suite

I've got an error in JSTS (JavaScript Topology Suite) library based on [JTS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jts-topo-suite/) (Java Topology Suite) v1.12 (r405).
But there is no error in the last build of JTS on the same test case. So I want to check this test case in older JTS v1.12.

[image]

However, I can't run the GUI (testbuilder.bat) due to error

> Could not find the main class. Program will exit.

[image]

under Windows, and in Ubuntu:

```
neadmin@myubuntu:~/SVN/JTS/jts/bin$ ./testbuilder.sh
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vividsolutions/jtstest/testbuilder/JTSTestBuilder
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
com.vividsolutions.jtstest.testbuilder.JTSTestBuilder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
Could not find the main class: com.vividsolutions.jtstest.testbuilder.JTSTestBuilder. Program will exit.
```

[image]

I have Windows 7 x64 (or Ubuntu 14.04) and Java 5u22 (or 6u45).

*I am asking about JTS, but it is related to JSTS...

I have Java and English on "you".*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using an SVN checkout of JTS so you need to compile it.

Alternatively just use the precompiled binaries from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jts-topo-suite/files/jts/